# Asserting text in nightwatchjs

Tags: assert, nightwatch.js

So in my nightwatchjs test I would like to check that the correct text is displayed for a couple of elements.

The first element (for example) is highlighted below in yellow;

[image]

I thought this would be simple to assert, but I just can't seem to get the text!

I've tried;

```
browser.expect.element('.why-buy-from-dealer h4').text.to.contain('Why buy from MCN Test Dealer');
```

and;

```
browser.getText("css selector", ".why-buy-from-dealer h4", function(result) {
console.log("getText result", result.value);
```

});

and;

```
browser.assert.containsText(".why-buy-from-dealer h4", "Why buy from MCN Test Dealer");
```

But each time I'm getting a result of "" (or null).

This is also the same for the element just under this one **.why-buy-from-dealer p**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the app / webpage built using angular? The text probably isn’t in the DOM yet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you wait for the element to be visible?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I’ve now realised my mistake. I was testing this using my headless setup, and as such the elements weren’t being rendered in the DOM. Testing this launching an actual browser rectified the issue.

Many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post.